# jQuery Create an Autocomplete Form

Tags: jquery, sqlite, autocomplete, forms, cs50

I need your help with the my search form in adjust.html. It should get input from the user "q" and suggest possible entries from database table "book"[[image: book table]. User should choose one of the suggestions and press button "Add".

As I run the program I get the following error: "RuntimeError: Missing input".[image: Error message] 
I'm grateful for your ideas and corrections.

Here is my JavaScript, Python and HTML codes:

```
function configure()
    {
    // Configure typeahead
    $("#q").typeahead({
        highlight: false,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        display: function(suggestion) { return null; },
        limit: 10,
        source: search,
        templates: {
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
                "<div>"+
                "{{Title}}, {{Author}}" +
                "</div>"
            )
       },
        updater: function(item) {
        //take selected item and submit to the form
        this.$element[0].value = item;
        this.$element[0].form.submit();
        return item;
        }
    });
    // Hide info window when text box has focus
    $("#q").focus(function(eventData) {
        info.close();
    });

    // Give focus to text box
    $("#q").focus();
}

// Search database for typeahead's suggestions
function search(query, syncResults, asyncResults)
{
    // Get places matching query (asynchronously)
    let parameters = {
        q: query
    };
    $.getJSON("/adjust", parameters, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        // Call typeahead's callback with search results (Author Title)
        asyncResults(data);
    });
}
```

python code:

```
@app.route("/adjust", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def search():
    """Search for books that match query"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        if not request.args.get("q"):
            return render_template("adjust.html")
        else:
            if request.args.get("q"): # handle ajax request
                q = request.args.get("q")  + "%"
            else:
                q = request.args.get("q")  + "%" # handle form submit

            books = db.execute("SELECT Title, Author FROM book WHERE Title LIKE :q OR Author LIKE :q", q=q)
    return jsonify(books)
```

html code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    Add your Book
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <form action="/adjust">
        <div class="form-group">
        <p>Choose your Book</p>
        <label class="sr-only" for="q">Title, Author</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Title, Author" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you post or take screenshot for the error

Comment: @ewwink I added screenshot to the question.

Comment: I tried your all code above and it work as expected. can you create jsfiddle with complete html and javascript?

Comment: Thanks @ewwink, here is the whole code. I think that the problem is somewhere in the connection between py and js. [link] (https://github.com/nailya6445/cs50_final_project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error not from Javascript but flask that cannot render `adjust.html` for sql the token is incorrect, it not `...LIKE: q` but `...LIKE :q`

and here fixed code

```
@app.route("/adjust", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def search():
    """Search for books that match query"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        if not request.args.get("q"):
            return render_template("adjust.html")
        else:
            if request.args.get("q"): # handle ajax request
                q = request.args.get("q")  + "%"
            else:
                q = request.form.get("q") + "%" # handle form submit

            books = db.execute("SELECT Title, Author FROM book WHERE Title LIKE :q OR Author LIKE :q", q=q)
    return jsonify(books)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works almost as it should. Could you please explain why do you use separate functions for "ajax request" and "form submit"? I would like to fill my form with selected search result. Such as if user select the item from the suggestions, it should appear in the search form - like in google search. (please see changes in js file). Should I now change the part "# handle form submit"?

Comment: it separated to follow original code, you can delete form submit if you want. please create another post for another problem It take time to solve this.

Comment: ok) here it is: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53923637/update-sqlite-database-in-python-after-the-item-from-dropdown-suggestions-select)