# update sqlite database in python after the item from dropdown suggestions selected

Tags: python, json, typeahead.js, cs50

My program must update table "idlist" [image: idlist table]in python after the item was selected from drop down suggestions in js. User selects the item, after that POST request in python adds it to the "idlist" table.
As I run the program I get the following error message: [image: error message]

I am grateful for your ideas and suggestions:

Here is my python code:

```
def search():
    """Search for books that match query"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        if not request.args.get("q"):
            return render_template("adjust.html")
        else:
            q = request.args.get("q")  + "%"
            books = db.execute("SELECT Title, Author FROM book WHERE Title LIKE :q OR Author LIKE :q", q=q)
        return jsonify(books)
    if request.method == "POST" and request.form.get("title"):
        Title = request.form.get("title")
        insert_book = db.execute("INSERT INTO idlist (id,Title1, Status) VALUES (:id, :Title1, :Status)", id=session["user_id"], Title1=Title, Status="Not started")
        return redirect("/")
    return render_template("adjust.html")
```

Here is html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Add your Book
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <form action="/adjust" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
        <p>Choose your Book</p>
        <label class="sr-only" for="q">Title, Author</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Title, Author" name="title" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is js:

```
function configure()
{
    // Configure typeahead
    $("#q").typeahead({
        highlight: false,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        display: function(suggestion) { return suggestion.Title; },
        limit: 10,
        source: search,
        templates: {
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
                "<div>"+
                "{{Title}}, {{Author}}" +
                "</div>"
            )
       }
    });

    // Give focus to text box
    $("#q").focus();
}


// Search database for typeahead's suggestions
function search(query, syncResults, asyncResults)
{
    // Get places matching query (asynchronously)
    let parameters = {
        q: query
    };
    $.getJSON("/adjust", parameters, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        // Call typeahead's callback with search results (Author Title)
        asyncResults(data);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   configure();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Ajax to Add new book it will make user confused because he don't know if it was added to the `idlist` or not, use the `Form POST` instead.

in `script.js` remove the following block

```
$("#q").on('typeahead:selected', function a(eventObject, suggestion, name) {
    ...
    ...
 });
```

and to add selected item to the input form, replace

```
display: function(suggestion) { return null; },
```

with

```
display: function(suggestion) { return suggestion.Title; },
```

to make form POST, in `adjust.html` replace

```
<form action="/adjust">
   ....
   <input class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Title, Author" type="text"/>
```

with

```
<form action="/addbook" method="POST">
    ....
    <input class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Title, Author" name="title" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

And the `addBook()` method

```
@app.route("/addbook", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def addbook():
    """Add selected book"""
    if request.method == "POST" and request.form.get("title"):
        Title = request.form.get("title")
        insert_book = db.execute("INSERT INTO idlist (id,Title1, Status) VALUES (:id, :Title1, :Status)", id=session["user_id"], Title1=Title, Status="Not started")
        return redirect("/")
    # no "title" in the form, return to Add new book page
    return redirect("/adjust")
```

Comment: Hi ewwink! I am so grateful to you! You are exactly right! It is much easier and elegant solution. 1) I removed 'typeahead:selected' block in js and added just request.form.get("title") for post request in python (also modifying the name of html form). 2) { return suggestion.Title; } is also perfect. 3) For the current request design, would not be easier to get rid of the `@app.route("/addbook", ...def addbook(): ....' and just extend '@app.route("/adjust"..)' with "POST" request to add a book? (please see the corrected code above)

Comment: Do you know how can I fill the form not only with Title but also with Author 'display: function(suggestion) { return suggestion.Title; }' ? Just adding suggestion.Author doesn't work.